# R ggiraph - no plot when running .R file

Tags: r, plot, ggiraph

How do I get the graph when executing a .R file? The file (`test.r`) looks like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggiraph)
gg <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = wt, color = factor(cyl)))
gg1 <-  gg + geom_point_interactive(aes(tooltip = gear), size = 5)
ggiraph(code = print(gg1))
```

I am running it with this command:

```
R < test.R --no-save
```

But nothing happens. If I just run R from the command line and enter the code line-by-line Firefox opens and shows a really nice graph with the wanted mouse-over label showing.

```
R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`R` generates a temporary .html file and then spawns a `gvfs-open` process to view that file (which in turn opens Firefox). When you are running your script from the command line, `R` exits and cleans up its temporary files before Firefox process has a chance to fully load. You can see this in effect by doing

```
$ R -q --interactive < test.R
> library(ggplot2)
> library(ggiraph)
> gg <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = wt, color = factor(cyl)))
> gg1 <-  gg + geom_point_interactive(aes(tooltip = gear), size = 5)
> ggiraph(code = print(gg1))
Save workspace image? [y/n/c]: 
gvfs-open: /tmp/RtmpPxtiZi/viewhtml3814550ff070/index.html: error opening location:
Error when getting information for file '/tmp/RtmpPxtiZi/viewhtml3814550ff070/index.html': No such file or directory
```

A simple fix is to add `Sys.sleep(5)` at the end of your script. This pauses `R` for a few seconds, allowing `gvfs-open` process to finish opening your temporary file in a browser window, before `R` exits and cleans up after itself.

Note that `R` will still remove the temporary `index.html` file when it exits after `Sys.sleep()`, but Firefox will already have a cache in memory.

EDIT: An alternative solution is to explicitly write out your interactive plot to an .html file that persists after `R` exits. You can do this by storing the result of `ggiraph` to a variable and then passing that to `htmlwidgets::saveWidget`:

```
myplot <- ggiraph(code = print(gg1))
htmlwidgets::saveWidget( myplot, "test.html" )
browseURL( "test.html" )
```

Comment: Thank you, your second solution works perfectly! Due to minor errors I also installed PANDOC with " sudo apt-get install pandoc "